# What is the difference between being good and being divine?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-being-good-and-being-divine/answer/Ted-Wrigley

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-being-good-and-being-divine/answer/Valerie-Yip-5

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-being-good-and-being-divine/answer/Yohan-John

Also what do you think about these answers?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. Link only posts are discouraged and "what do you think" questions are off-topic on this site because they invite personal opinions. Try to summarize what it is in those links that is essential to your question and rephrase to make it more or less objectively answerable (e.g. focusing on the difference according to some particular school of thought).

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on Plato (and classical Greek philosophy), so it may be not what you are looking for, but it might help: Good, in general, as you can imagine - the most "Good" (The best is not right word here) is God itself, and anything that is somehow is good 'has some sort of share' with "The Good", therefor with The God, so Good is Divine. If something is more "Good", then that is more "Divine" and vice versa.
Also, "Bad"/"Evil" has no substance, or real ontology - it's just lack of Divinity, that means lack of Good.

*Conclusion: anything that is Good is Divine, and anything that is Divine is Good.*

Comment: Not quite. I think you are trying to retell Republic, but the Form of the Good there is not God (it is impersonal and has no will), and in fact there is no "God" in Plato, only gods, often metaphorical. Moreover, in [Euthyphro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euthyphro_dilemma) he argues that gods command things because those things are morally good independently, so good and divine are different things. Although divinity is accompanied by partaking in the Good it has more to do with nous, mind. Evil as lack of good is a neoplatonist doctrine introduced by Plotinus centuries after Plato.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.At first, it's not from Republic, but from Platonism in General (including Neo-Platonism).
In Euthypho's there is unsolved problem, not assertion that "things are morally good independently".
"in fact there is no "God" in Plato" - is not fact.